# Using Turbolinks with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide, turbolinks

When I run my selenium test without the turbolinks gem installed in my Ruby on Rails app, the tests pass. When I include turbolinks, the tests fail. For example if the test starts off

Open            /
clickAndWait    link=Sign in
type            id=session_email     any@example.com

Then I will get an error
"[error]Element id=session_email not found.

When I look at the page source, the session_email id is still there with turbolinks installed. I found this page, http://www.digitalkingdom.org/rlp/tiki-index.php?page=Selenium+And+Javascript, which seems to indicate there could be a problem with detecting the page has fully loaded.

Is there away to fix this without changing hundreds of lines in my test suites? If not, is there a reliable selenium method that can test that a turbolinked page has fully loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some help with the github [turbolinks-compatability project](https://github.com/reed/turbolinks-compatibility/issues/6#issuecomment-15526506), I am able to provide a partial answer to this question.

If the turbolinks gem is being used, then you will need to modify your selenium test cases in order to make sure the page is really loaded.  For example, if your test has the following code in it

```
Open /
clickAndWait link=Sign in
type id=session_email any@example.com
```

then it needs to be modified to

```
Open /
click link=Sign in
waitForElementPresent id=session_email
type id=session_email any@example.com
```

There are a number of "waitFor" modifiers you can used, depending on what is the feature on the page you want to test next.

However, if the test involves a javascript pop up, then you should not add a waitFor command.  So for example if you have at test like

```
clickAndWait link=Delete
assertConfirmation   Are you Sure?
```

you should not modify the code. Indeed adding a waitFor test hangs execution in the case of javascript popups.

This solution involves line-by-line manual modification of the code. I have opened up an [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/selenium-users/turbolinks/selenium-users/LE6bxRBwhc4/0PrYl11n0i8J) on the Selenium Users group to see if there is some better way to handle this problem.